# Why does the XDB reindexing not start

Tags: xdb, indexing

I am attempting to resolve this error seen in the `xdb xcollection search logs`

`Tokens are incompatible, they have different set of shards.`

I executed the following `powershell` script to verify the shard information in the `xdb index` is correct

```
param([string]$Token = (Read-Host "xxxxxxx"))

$bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($Token)
$ms = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
$bf = [System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter]::new()
$dict = $bf.Deserialize($ms);
Write-Output $dict
```

Indeed the `shard information` in the `index` is incorrect.

My next step was to rebuild the `index` and this is where it's seemingly failing.  I started it last night at around 10pm EST.  The `Stage` hasn't changed from "Starting"

[image]

I reviewed the `logs` and I do not see any `errors` in the `logs`.  Any help is appreciated.